# Socket.io - angularjs connects to the server, i see the logs, but i cannot emit anything

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, nginx

I am using nodejs and angularjs in an nginx together with socket.io but i am struggling to emit any messages an listen to events.

I played around a lot configuring nginx based on nginx-socket.io suggested settings.

When **connecting** from client side, i see the logs into the server. I am **connecting** like this

```
 var socket = io.connect('https://myserver.com/socket.io', { 'transports': ['websocket', 'polling', 'xhr-polling'] });
```

This is some part of the **server** side code:

```
var app = express();
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);

httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Running on port ' + port + '.');
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('======= a user connected =======');

    socket.emit('welcome', { message: 'Welcome!' });

    socket.on('enterRoom', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('++++++++ user disconnected ++++++++');
    });
});
```

I have the following factory right after my connection:

```
    return {
    on: function(eventName, callback) {
        socket.on(eventName, function() {
            var args = arguments;
            console.log(args);
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {


                callback.apply(socket, args);
            });
        });
    },
    emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {
        socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
            var args = arguments;
            console.log(args);
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                if (callback) {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Then i **inject** my factory *'socketio'* into my controller, and try to  *lister/communicate* with my server.

Part of controller code:

```
socketio.on('connect', function() {
    socketio.on('welcome', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      socketio.emit('enterRoom', { my: 'data' });
    });
});
```

When refreshing i always see the "user connected" and "user disconnected" logs into the server logs, but i cannot see anything else besides that.

I have already set the following configurations also:

```
location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `location /socket.io {` ?

Comment: Yes. No difference @ShawnC.

Comment: After a day of research, i found out that having multiple instances i should also use `sticky-session` aka 'session affinity' or/and clustering in order to ensure that the sticky-session module balances connection between workers based on their ip.So all the requests from the same client would go to the same worker.